# Can I overlay the coordinates of variables of one PCA over the coordinates of individuals from a second PCA and still interprete the results?

Tags: r, pca

I do have two sets of data: Abundance data and environmental data and need to "link" them or "overlay" them in a PCA:

I want to conduct a **PCA** in **R** which gives me the individuals **Ciliate** species as Individuals and the environmental parameters as variables.
What I do have are two different dataframes.
"**abundance**"  where the abundance of the different species at the sampled sites are given and
"environment" where the **environmental parameters** of the sampled sites are given. So I have one parameter in common in eacht dataframe: the sites! 
If i conduct PCAs I either get a plot with the sites as individuals and the environmental parameters as variables or a plot with the species as individuals and the sites as variables. What I need, would be to link the datasets by the parameter site so that I can conduct a PCA with the ciliate species as individuals ans the environmental parameters as variables. So i would somehow need to link the two PCAs/dataframes over the common parameter site.
What I did so far- i did two different PCAs and rememberd the coordinates of the individuals (ciliate species) of PCA1 and the coordinates of the variables of PCA2 (environmental parameters) and biploted them-> The graph is exactly what I would need, but is it still interpretable as a PCA, so the dataframes really linked by the site parameter?
Or did simply trick with the data and loose the interpretability?

Another option I tried is to calculate the environmental paramteres of each ciliate species by weighted mean (weighted by the abundance of the ciliates at the site) and conduct a PCA on a dataframe with ciliate species and the weighted mean of the environmental parameters...Which works but I think I loose a lot of information on this way...What do you think?

```
#Create random dataframe of abundance data, I am sure this can be done simpler and more elegant than this ;)
    species<-c("spec1", "spec2", "spec3", "spec 4", "spec 5", "spec 6", "spec7")
    site1<-c(2,4,19,34,3,6,9)
    site2<-c(5,8,9,12,0,1,1)
    site3<-c(23,56,7,1,1,1,2)
    site4<-c(4,6,2,8,5,1,7)
    abundance<-data.frame(species,site1,site2,site3,site4)
    rownames(abundance)<-abundance$species
    abundance<-abundance[,-1]
    #Create random dataframe of abundance data
    #environmental parameters of the sites
    X<-c("site1","site2","site3","site4")
    Temp<-c(24,24.5,23.5,25)
    Chla<-c(2.2,1.5,2.0,3.4)
    Plo<-c(1000,2000,1500,200)
    Plo2<-c(200,400,600,200)
    environment<-data.frame(X,Temp,Chla,Plo,Plo2)
    rownames(environment)<-environment$X
    environment<-environment[,-1]
    ###PCA on abundance data
    #hellinger pre-transformation of abundance data
    library(vegan)
    abu.h<-decostand(abundance,"hellinger")
    abu.h.pca<-prcomp(abu.h)
    envir.pca<-prcomp(environment,scale=TRUE)
    biplot(abu.h.pca)
    ##and now I would need to discard the sites vectors and overlay it with 
    #the environmental sites factors, due to my prof?
    #Graph of individuals 
    fviz_pca_ind(abu.h.pca) 
    ##get coordinates 
    library(factoextra)
    ind<-get_pca_ind(abu.h.pca) 
    head(ind$coord) 
    #x in biplot 
    ind<-ind$coord 
    ind<-ind[,1:2]
    ind 
    #y variables 
    # Extract the results for variables only

    vari<-get_pca_var(abu.h.pca) 
    var<-vari$coord 
    var<-var[,1:2] 
    var 
    biplot(ind, var, var.axes = TRUE)
```

Comment: Seems more appropriate for CrossValidated.com where questions of statistical validity are more on-topic than is the case on SO.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a good advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done what you're describing, but I know you can do a relate to the environmental (abiotic) data with vector overlays on top of an nMDS. If you can do that with a PCA, I'm not sure, but at least my PRIMER manual mentions that a PCA of abiotic data using Euclidean distance is a good fit with an nMDS of the biotic data, and is how PRIMER's BEST function works. But this isn't PRIMER.

See the `vegan::envfit` function. The [intro vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vignettes/intro-vegan.pdf) covers it briefly. [Vegan tutor covers it a bit more.](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/opetus/metodi/vegantutor.pdf)

I transposed the species data and did it using an nMDS of the species data.

```
library(vegan)

species <-c ("spec1", "spec2", "spec3", "spec 4", "spec 5", "spec 6", "spec7")
site1 <- c(2,4,19,34,3,6,9)
site2 <- c(5,8,9,12,0,1,1)
site3 <- c(23,56,7,1,1,1,2)
site4 <- c(4,6,2,8,5,1,7)
abundance <- data.frame(species,site1,site2,site3,site4)
rownames(abundance) <- abundance$species
abundance <- abundance[,-1]
abundance <- t(abundance)

X <- c ("site1","site2","site3","site4")
Temp <- c(24,24.5,23.5,25)
Chla <- c(2.2,1.5,2.0,3.4)
Plo <- c(1000,2000,1500,200)
Plo2 <- c(200,400,600,200)
environment <- data.frame(X,Temp,Chla,Plo,Plo2)
rownames(environment) <- environment$X
environment <- environment[,-1]

AbEnvMDS <- metaMDS(abundance, k = 2)
AbEnvFit <- envfit(AbEnvMDS, environment)

plt <- plot(AbEnvMDS) # displays both sites (empty circles) and species (red +)
plt <- plot(AbEnvMDS, display = "species") # displays only species (red +)
plt
identify(plt, what = "species") # choose your points
plot(AbEnvFit) # overlays your environment
```

[image: Graph of results]